# Is that possible to dynamically create instance in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration, omniauth

The senario is that I have a model named App_clients, and models named Twitter and Facebook both inherit from it:

```
Model App
def initialize(provider,access_token)
end

Model Twitter < App
def initialize(provider, access_token)
  @client = Twitter::API.new(access_token) 
end

Model Facebook < App
def initialize(provider, access_token)
  @client = Facebook::API.new(access_token) 
end
```

My question is that is that possible to have a method in Apps_controller or Model App to create the instance of app's client depending on the params[:provider] ? 
I don't want to add to many if or elsif to decide which is desired client

BTW, I am using omniauth to integrated the authentications of Twitter and Facebook.

Very appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is.

You can use

```
klass = "#{params[:provider].to_s}".constantize
instance = klass.new # provide arguments here
```

So for example if you receive a request with provider: "Twitter" it will return the Twitter class.

Just have some caution doing this and validate the provider param you get so that users won't be able to use it for bad purposes.

Also, [read the docs about constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize).